# why uss is get larger and larger when an app is re-launched several times in android?

Tags: android, uss

I got this confusion: when i launched app A from Home screen, check the uss using this command "adb shell procrank | grep 'A'", then back to Home by the "Back" menu key; then re-launched A and back to Home several times, the uss is become larger and larger. The uss number is like 19296, 19312,19324, 19340...
    Any one has any ideas about this? So many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

USS represents the memory being utilized by a specific process. Memory that would be released if the process was terminated. If you're seeing that figure increase like a runaway train you probably have a memory leak. Pressing the back/home button does not guarantee that your application process will be terminated, and relaunching through whatever means will just bring that process to the foreground if it is still alive.

Edit: [Read here for a good explanation of how this works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android).

Comment: @himalayagiant Good to hear, perhaps you could mark this as the answer.